# Send an image in golang without downloading it

Tags: file, post, go, request

**What's the problem**

I have a url with an image in it, and I want to send the image in a post request. Is there a way to do it without downloading the file locally?

**What have I tried**

Usually I would download the image, send the image, and delete the file. Is there a better way?

```
  response, e := http.Get(url)
if e != nil {
    log.Fatal(e)
} 
writer := multipart.NewWriter(body)
  part, err := writer.CreateFormFile(paramName, filepath.Base(path))
  if err != nil {
      return nil, err
  }
  _, err = io.Copy(part, file)
```

Comment: You cannot avoid downloading the image. You can avoid saving it to a temporary file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to create a temporary file. Remember that `http.Request` takes an `io.Reader` (or an `io.ReadCloser`), and since `response.Body` is an `io.ReadCloser` it will happily read directly from your existing HTTP response body from your previous request.

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, response.Body)
```

For a multipart upload, you can simply call `multipart.CreatePart()` and then `io.Copy()` directly from the response body of the original HTTP GET request to the writer you're using. You still don't need a temporary file.

Comment: I forgot to mention I am using multipart, I will edit my post

Comment: I fixed it, can I just use the response.Body as the file when I use `.io.Copy`?

Comment: Now your question is quite different to the one I answered. I think it will be very confusing. And some of the code seems to be missing.

Comment: Sorry, I added the request back. I need to bridge the response.Body into a file somehow.

Comment: @PLZHELP You still don't need a temporary file. Just `io.Copy()` directly from the reader to the writer after each time you call `CreatePart()`.